# VideoCompress Mediainfo error with flutter

Tags: flutter, mediainfo, video-compression

Hello I am having an issue where when trying to set the type of a variable mediainfo flutter requires that `VideoCompress.compressVideo();` returns a type of `Future<MediaInfo>`

Syntax Error is as follows `A value of type 'Future<MediaInfo>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'MediaInfo'.`

And when using `VideoCompress.getMediaInfo(file)` it seems to **not** return a MediaInfo type as when I try to assign it to a variable it fails to provide the `.path` method.

Here is an example of the code.

```
static Future<MediaInfo> compressVideo(file, context) async{
    await VideoCompress.compressVideo(file,
        quality: VideoQuality.HighestQuality, deleteOrigin: true);
    final info = VideoCompress.getMediaInfo(file);

    return info;
```

Attempt of trying to access `.path` [click me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kwal9.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that's because compressVideo function doesn't return  MediaInfo, it returns Future so you need to await for it.

```
final info = await VideoCompressApi.compressVideo(filePath, context);
setState((){
  compressedInfo = info.path;
});
```

**Edit:**
you can also use:

```
VideoCompressApi.compressVideo(filePath, context).then((info) {
  setState(() => compressedInfo = info.path);
});
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked. Hope you have a great week.

Comment: if you have the time I would appreciate if you would take a look at this question it relates to the answer you provided (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72449555/flutter-error-when-using-null-check-operator-with-android-emulator)