# Flutter error when using null check operator with android emulator

Tags: android, flutter, null

I am dealing with an unusual error. That is when I run my flutter app on an android device. Flutter seems to restrict the use of the (!) operator. Usually, it works on an IOS simulator. The error it gives me is always something simillar to `_CastError (Null check operator used on a null value)`

I understand the (!) operator can't be used on a null value but in my case, I initialize a  `MediaInfo? compressedInfo;` variable then set its value in a setState and check that it's not null. As you can see here

```
               await VideoCompress.compressVideo(filePath,
                      quality: VideoQuality.HighestQuality,
                      deleteOrigin: true);
               final info = await VideoCompress.getMediaInfo(filePath);
               setState(() {
                 compressedInfo = info;
               });
               Navigator.of(context).pop();
               print('stage');
               if (compressedInfo != null) {
                   Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                     builder: (c) => PreviewVideo(
                       videoPath: 
                          compressedInfo.path!.toString(),
                          title: title.trim(),
                         )));
               }
```

Comment: In this case you checked if compressedInfo is not null but the path still might be null so change the if statement to : if(compressedInfo != null && compressedInfo.path != null) {}

Comment: I tried but had no luck, I updated the question and changed the code. It now keys the error and highlights the `info` variable as a _Casterror. If you have any more ideas please do let me know thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use the 2.1.0 version which excludes null safety, and also the MediaInfo does not returns null

video_compress: ^2.1.0

```
static Future<MediaInfo?> compressVideo(String videoPath)async{
try{
  MediaInfo? mediaInfo = await VideoCompress.compressVideo(videoPath,quality: VideoQuality.LowQuality,includeAudio: true,deleteOrigin: false);
  return mediaInfo;
}
on Exception catch(error){
  print('Vide compress error ${error.toString()}');
  throw Exception('Some error Ocurred while compressing');
}
```

}

Comment: Please use formatting guidelines https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help